# Imported Code from Github into Eclipse. Getting build path error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this error when building my project:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/amithiyer/git/Android/library/bin/library.jar'

I don't know what I am missing in my dependencies.  If you need more information, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: ok thank you @MichaelGaskill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest switching to Android Studio, it would be easier to manage all the dependencies in a much cleaner and better way.

Comment: thanks for responding Rohan. I actually was using Android Studio but had a bunch of problems and am trying Eclipse now just to see if its any better

Comment: What issues particularly? I could help.

Comment: I was importing the same android app from github and I was getting the error Autogeneration Error
            Cannot mark directory '/Users/amithiyer/Documents/Enpower-2/gen' as source root, because it is not located under content root of module 'Enpower'

Comment: Sorry if I am not being very clear. I had only worked with iOS apps until about a month ago

Comment: I could not understand.

Comment: I actually got it to work in Android Studio if you can believe it.  I do appreciate the help very much.